# Excel: Transpor de 5 em 5 células

Tags: microsoft-excel, macro

Olá,
Tenho o seguinte problema, minha planilha tem centenas de dados todos na mesma coluna dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu quero encontrar uma maneira de transferir esses valores para outras células, de forma que na primeira linha apareçam os 5 primeiros dados, na segunda linha os próximos 5, na terceira linha os próximos 5, e assim vai.. igual nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu quero fazer isso de forma automática, ou com macro ou com alguma fórmula que eu consiga selecionar e arrastar para as outras células.
Alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1):

### Solução

Transposição dinâmica deverá ser usada, você pode transpor manualmente ou com uma função `Transpose`. Neste exemplo será feito um por um.

### Código

Cria um array com a coluna dos dados e depois insere uma por uma em outra planilha.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    'Declarações

    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long, j As Long, linha As Long, coluna As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Declara a planilha com os dados
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha2")
    'Em ws1:
    With ws1
        'ÚltimaLinha
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Array
        Arr() = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value2
        linha = 1
        coluna = 1
        'Loop em cada elemento da Array
        For j = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
           ws2.Cells(linha, coluna) = Arr(j, 1)
           coluna = coluna + 1
           'Quando preencher 5 células, passa para próxima linha e zera contador de coluna
           If coluna = 6 Then
            linha = linha + 1
            coluna = 1
           End If
        Next j
    End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### Resultado

Com os dados na planilha Planilha1:

```
+----+
| A  |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 20 |
+----+
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |
|  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

### Explicação

#### ws1 e ws2

Declara o nome das duas planilhas a serem usadas.

```
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha2")
```

#### LastRow

Obtém a última linha da coluna desejada, no caso do exemplo a coluna A

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

#### Arr

Cria uma Array() com os dados da coluna desejada.

```
 Arr() = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value2
```

#### Loop

Loop do primeiro ao último elemento da array

```
For j = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
Next j
```

#### Escrever na Planilha

Escreve cada elemento da array na Planilha2

```
ws2.Cells(linha, coluna) = Arr(j, 1)
```

#### Condição

Quando o quinto elemento for preenchido na linha, zera o contador de coluna e passa para a próxima linha.

```
 If coluna = 6 Then
    linha = linha + 1
    coluna = 1
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução mais simples seria:
Num novo documento, considere que a coluna "A" são os seus dados e que nas colunas B em diante serão organizados os dados de A de cinco em cinco.
Em B1, B2, B3, B4 e B5 insira os números de 1 a 5.
Em C1, C2, C3, C4 e C5 insira a fórmula: B1+5; B2+5; B3+5 ...
Copie e cole o intervalo C1:C5 quantas vezes forem necessárias a partir de D1. Para dez mil linhas vai ir até BXY5.
Copie e cole o intervalo B1:BXY5 usando a opção somente valores. Cole por cima do próprio intervalo B1:BXY5.
Na célula B7, escreva =concatenar("-";"A";B1).
Arraste essa fórmula até a coluna desejada (BXY) e até a linha B11.
Em B13, copie e cole usando somente valores o intervalo B7:BXY11
Depois selecione o intervalo B13:BXY17, vá em substituir (Ctrl+L) e mande substituir o "-" por "=". Pronto!
Tá feito e postado pra vc em: https://www.sendspace.com/file/ovwi8y